# ConactMap to make sequence API calls with progress

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I want call tow APIs sequentially and it working with me but I see this error in the console after the activity has been destroyed  :

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.deve.blueage.ui.register.RegisterActivity has leaked window DecorView@29a83fa[RegisterActivity] that was originally added here
```

and here is my code :

```
  disposable.add(networkManager.postRequest(Endpoints.REGISTER_URL, param, UserModel.class)
                .map(this::storeUser)
                .concatMap(user -> {
                    HashMap<String, Object> param2 = new HashMap<>();
                    param2.put("username", user.getEmail());
                    param2.put("password", password);
                    return networkManager.postRequest(Endpoints.LOGIN_URL, param2, String.class)
                        .delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .map(this::storeUserToken);
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe(v -> baseView.showLoading())
                .doOnTerminate(() -> baseView.hideLoading())
                .subscribe(v -> signUpLiveData.setValue(true), this::processError));
```

Any idea what is getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `networkManager.postRequest` flow is still working after `baseView` lifecycle events. So it keeps the link to the destroyed view - this is not good.
I'd recommend one of these solutions:

- Consider using some kind of medium in the chain `data-> medium-> view`. It allows not having links to views from lifecycle-unaware
  components.
- Link your Observable to View's lifecycle events. So, your
  view can trigger `dispose()` for the Observable flow, when the view is being destroyed.